# Not unique table alias

Tags: mysql

```
set @carer_fname = 'Carername';
set @carer_sname = 'Carersname';
select concat_ws(' ', C.child_fname, C.child_sname) as 'Child Name'
,C.child_carer
,A.activity_name, A.activity_day
from Child C, Activity A
inner join Child C on CA.child_id = C.child_id
inner join Activity A on CA.activity_id = A.activity_id
order by child_sname
```

Response is: Error Code: 1066. Not unique table/alias: 'C'

Not exactly sure why C not unique comes up

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You have the alias `C` twice, the first in the `FROM` clause, the second in the first `INNER JOIN`. Every single alias within a query must be unique, so change one of those.

Comment: What `C` does `C.child_fname` refer to?

Comment: can you share your table info? where CA comes ?

Comment: Mixing implicit and explicit joins is dangerous. 'the precedence of the comma operator is less than that of INNER JOIN, CROSS JOIN, LEFT JOIN, and so on. If you mix comma joins with the other join types when there is a join condition, an error of the form Unknown column 'col_name' in 'on clause' may occur.' - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Dravenzo you are using multiple instances of the table `Child` and giving it the alias of `C` both times:

```
set @carer_fname = 'Carername';
set @carer_sname = 'Carersname';
select concat_ws(' ', C.child_fname, C.child_sname) as 'Child Name'
,C.child_carer
,A.activity_name, A.activity_day
from -->Child C<--, Activity A -- first instance of aliasing Child as C
inner join -->Child C<-- on CA.child_id = C.child_id -- second instance of aliasing Child as C
inner join Activity A on CA.activity_id = A.activity_id
order by child_sname
```

It's not really clear what you are trying to do with this query because in your `FROM` clause you are listing both tables `Child` and `Activity` and then using `JOIN` statements in a confusing manner. Also, you are referring to an alias of `CA` but you aren't stating which table should be aliased as `CA`.

This is only a guess at what you want to do with your query because of the confusing aspects of what you have listed, but try something like this:

```
set @carer_fname = 'Carername';
set @carer_sname = 'Carersname';
select concat_ws(' ', C.child_fname, C.child_sname) as 'Child Name',
    C.child_carer,
    A.activity_name, 
    A.activity_day
from Child C
inner join Activity A on A.activity_id = C.activity_id
order by C.child_sname
```

I suggest reading up on MySQL joins in the official documentation [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html) or googling `MySQL JOINS tutorial`, there are loads of tutorials out there.